# How to send attachment/contentdocument to external system using Apex

Tags: integration, attachment, httprequest

I am trying to send a simple test document to the external system.
The request goes through well when I do it using Postman but as soon as I try to send similar request from salesforce it comes back with Bad Request as response.

Any quick tip or help on this one would be very helpful. Let me know if any further detail is require. I have also tried with encoding it using base64 but no luck.

P.s the external system is Noggin. Below is the sample code.

```
ContentVersion file = [SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = 'Id' Limit 1]; 
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setMethod('POST'); 
    request.setHeader('authorization', 'authToken'); //same as Postman
    request.setEndpoint('endPointURl');  //same as Postman
    request.setBodyAsBlob(file.VersionData); 
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the error message or response status that you get in Apex, I'm going to take guesses.

Here are some things you can try:

1. Make sure that the target endpoint URL is added in **Setup > Remote Site Settings**.
2. Try to add a `Content-Type` header to your post request (Postman may be doing this automatically). You should be able to send the blob without having to convert to base64.

Comment: So the response what I get when trying to send the request is System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]
Yep I did try adding content-type as multipart/form-data; and send but no luck getting the same response. 

Yep the url is added in Setup > remote site setting.

Comment: Try to use the right binary MIME type such as `application/pdf`. If you're not encoding with base64, you won't need `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Actually I just got to know that the request is expecting the date in form-data type only. and not just base64 encoded or string format. I am trying to look on how we can send files using formdata format in apex. 

If you have any suggestion/idea would really appreciate.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Could you please share the solution if you have found one?